# www CNAME seems to override app CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I'm building Rails app hosted on Heroku that lives on a subdomain `app.example.com`. Part of the app is an outdated site that lives in the root directory. I want to configure a CNAME for my domain to direct hits to `www.example.com` or `example.com` to an unbounce.com page I've set up, while still allowing hits to `app.example.com` to be handled by my app.

I already have an `app` CNAME that points to my app's Heroku url and works (or rather was working) fine. I also had a `www` CNAME that pointed to the same Heroku url (`http://`example-app-1234.herokuapp.com/`). Lastly, my domains's A-Record points to the IP address for Heroku.

Today I edited the CNAME in my DNS setting for `www` so that it points to `unbouncepages.com`, following instructions from [here](http://documentation.unbounce.com/hc/en-us/articles/203661044-Mapping-Your-Landing-Page-Domain-CNAME-Records-). That part works. The problem I have now is that for some reason, hits to `app.example.com` are being redirected to `unbounce.com`, bypassing my app altogether. If I view a live stream of the logs from Heroku, I can see that app traffic doesn't even hit the server, it goes straight to `unbounce.com`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Give us the actual domain name, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: I figured out the problem. My setup was correct from the start. I just needed to clear out my browser cache. I tried doing a hard reload and it wasn't working, but once I cleared the cache it worked fine.